# Может ли несогласованное определение уточнять или пояснять значение согласованного, не обособляясь?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, определения

> В конце исследования у всех пациентов было отмечено **клинически значимое улучшение общего показателя опросника на 10 баллов и более**.

Под "общим показателем" имеется в виду сумма всех набранных баллов. Корректна ли выделенная часть без всяких знаков препинания, если, согласно принятому в данном исследовании определению, клинически значимое улучшение — это улучшение на 10 баллов и более? Получается, что фразы "клинически значимое улучшение" и "на 10 баллов и более" означают одно и то же, между ними можно поставить "то есть".

Немного переделаем предложение:

> В конце исследования у всех пациентов было отмечено **существенное улучшение общего показателя опросника на 12 баллов и более**.

Корректна ли такая формулировка? В данном случае выражение "существенное улучшение" не термин, а обычное сочетание прилагательного с существительным. Получается, что фраза "на 12 баллов и более" уточняет значение слова "существенное".

---

Также интересны следующие примеры из интернета:

> **Двойная терапия любым пероральным антикоагулянтом и клопидогрелом** (по 75 мг в день) может рассматриваться как альтернатива тройной терапии для отдельных пациентов.

"Двойная" означает, что в рамках этой терапии используют два препарата. Они указаны в качестве несогласованных определений.

> У ВИЧ-инфицированных пациентов P. aeruginosa [вид бактерий] может вызывать инфекции различной локализации. Для их лечения применяют **стандартную терапию комбинацией антипсевдомонадного бета-лактамного антибиотика и аминогликозида**, однако и в этом случае у данной категории часто развиваются резистентность и рецидивы, даже когда проведенный курс лечения представляется успешным.

Если предположить, что имеется только один вариант стандартной терапии указанных инфекций, то, как я полагаю, возникает такая же ситуация, как в моем первом примере: несогласованное определение имеет то же значение, что и согласованное, и после "стандартную терапию" можно поставить "то есть".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корректная запись:

*В конце исследования у всех пациентов было отмечено клинически значимое улучшение общего показателя опросника ―  **на 10 баллов и более**.*

В данном случае мы действительно имеем **согласованное определение** (клинически значимое улучшение), которое в числовом выражении имеет конкретный показатель в этой отрасли. Поэтому указывая его в предложении, мы просто **уточняем** (напоминаем) эту величину.

Соответственно, числовая информация имеет **дополнительный характер** и обособляется тире, реже используется двоеточие и скобки.

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса**

Никто из чиновников среднего звена и слышать об этом не хотел, потому что это существенное увеличение коллектива ― **на пятнадцать-восемнадцать человек.** [И. Э. Кио.  (1995-1999)]

Активное экономическое развитие Казахстана в этот период также обеспечило существенный рост ВВП на душу населения ― **до 117%** по сравнению со средним уровнем. [Андрей Косарев.  2014]

Этому способствуют не только меры «Фармы-2020», но и существенный рост рынка (**с 2008 года он увеличился почти вдвое, до 1 трлн рублей**), а также другие меры правительства, обозначающего здравоохранение и фарму своими приоритетами. [Галина Костина, 2014]

В Красноярске отмечен очень существенный рост цен на строящееся жилье за 2004 год ― **порядка 60%.** [Елена Ермолаева. Плюс 30% за год (2004) // «Континент Сибирь» (Новосибирск), 17.12.2004]

Возможно, именно вследствие этих процессов за указанный период произошел существенный рост числа женщин в управленческом персонале США: **с 16 до 40%** (Г. Пауэлл, 1990; ).

Важно отметить и существенный рост внутреннего потребления проката черных металлов ― **25, 6 млн т**, что, по предварительным данным, на 15, 3% выше уровня 2002 года.

Comment: Спасибо. Можете, пожалуйста, прокомментировать два последних примера в моем вопросе (после черты)? Требуется ли в них обособление?